# How make controls on map like in Windows Map app

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, bing-maps, uwp-maps

How can I make controls on map like in Windows Map app, square and translucent, rather than the standard round.

By default map control has round zoom-buttons, but I need make they like in Windows Map (win10)

I can't edit `<maps:MapControl>` style in Blend or in VS2015.

Have tried to create template for `Button` or `BaseButton` in App.xaml but it doesn't help.

So, it's also interesting for me how is it possible to get standard template of `MapControl`?

[image: Controls screenshot]

Comment: I had the same issue... so I disabled all build in buttons of the contol and added my own on top of the Map Control. But true, bit of a shame the build in app uses other controls then the one of the SDK

Answer (score -1):

I don't think that you'll get far by modifying the MapControl style. First of all, bookmark [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299122.aspx) as you find the standard templates there. As an alternative you can use Blend and "create copy" of the template. The MapControl is quite natively written, so there's few XAML and thus no style, I don't know.

I wonder why you do have round zoom buttons (the MapControl shouldn't have them by default). However, then simply add other buttons next to the MapControl, style them like you want and in the code you call the methods which modify the map accordingly (`TryZoomInAsync`, `TryZoomOutAsync`, `TryTiltAsync`, `TryRotateAsyc`).

Comment: Thus, Microsoft in native Maps app use custom controls?